# Ler e exibir um PDF dentro de uma pasta zipada sem extrair ela

Tags: c#, pdf

É possível fazer isso ou eu realmente tenho que extrair o arquivo antes para depois lê-lo?

**No meu código estou fazendo assim:**

```
  string zipPath = @"C:\Users\Analistas\Desktop\ZipFile.zip";

        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
        {
            var sample = archive.GetEntry("PdfFile.pdf");  
            string pdfContent = ReadPdfFile("PdfFile.pdf");
            if (sample != null)
            {
                using (var zipEntryStream = sample.Open())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(pdfContent);
                }
            }
        }
```

**E o método para ler PDF:**

```
        public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

                    currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                    text.Append(currentText);
                }
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
            return text.ToString();
        }
```

> Não está exibindo nada.

Comment: acredito que pelo `fileName`, teria que extrair um stream e constuir um clone do pdf a partir dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível ler o pdf que está dentro de uma pasta zipada sem ter que extraí-lo.
Basta instanciar o objeto `PdfReader` usando o objeto `Stream` do arquivo desejado.

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(ZipFileStream);
```

Uma sugestão seria alterar o seu código para passar o objeto `Stream` para o método `ReadPdfFile`

```
var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath);
var sample = archive.GetEntry("PdfFile.pdf");  
var zipEntryStream = sample.Open();

var pdfContent = ReadPdfFile(zipEntryStream);
```

E o método `ReadPdfFile` deve ser alterado para ler objeto `Stream`.

```
public string ReadPdfFile(Stream fileStream)
{
    ...
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileStream);
    ...
}
```